# Addition of two queries sql

Tags: sql

I have two queries:

```
SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Money)) / 1048576.0 from Money

SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Cc)) / 1048576.0 from CC
```

If ran individually they return 20 and 30. 
I want to combine these to get a result as 50.

Can this be done in one line? Rather then assigning two variables values of query 1 and 2 and adding them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(sm) as total_sum
from (
  SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Money)) / 1048576.0 as sm 
  from Money

  union all

  SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Cc)) / 1048576.0 
  from CC
) t
```

Comment: You might want to add in the `sm` alias.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Can you please explain what does 't' at the end of the script represents? If i run without it, i get error. Why do i need that?

Comment: @NoviceMe. that's an alias for the derived table. Similar to a table alias (`.. from foo f ...`)

Answer (score 1):

A standard way of doing this is using `cross join`:

```
select val1 + val2
from (SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Money)) / 1048576.0 as val1 from Money
     ) t1 cross join
     (SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Cc)) / 1048576.0 as val2 from CC
     ) t2
```

Comment: Thanks! How can i assign val1 + val2 to an int variable in above script?

Comment: If you want to give it a column name, then you would use `select (val1 + val2) as TheSum . . . `.  If you want to assign it to a variable, that depends on the scripting language, but is usually something like `select @TheSum = (val1 + val2) . . .`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
(SUM(DATALENGTH(Money)) / 1048576.0) + SUM(DATALENGTH(Cc)) / 1048576.0
from Money, CC
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work:

```
Select 
   (SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Money)) / 1048576.0 from Money) 
 + (SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Cc)) / 1048576.0 from CC)
```

At least it does in my DB engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(S)
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Money)) / 1048576.0 S from Money
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM(DATALENGTH(Cc)) / 1048576.0 from CC
) Q;
```